# Intervalo de enteros en expresion regular

Tags: python, regex

Estaba resolviendo algo y me encontré con esta prueba y no entiendo bien qué es lo que sucede.

La duda es, me muestra 3456'7' ¿Por qué aparece el 7 en la salida si estoy delimitando de `[3-6]`?

¿Qué está prevaleciendo por sobre el limite que pongo entre corchetes?

```
sentencia = 'Esto es la prueba 123456789 \n de expresiones regulares en python.'
#sentencia = 'Esto.'
pa = re.compile(r'[3-6]\d\d\d\d')
siesta = pa.finditer(sentencia)
for sies in siesta:
    print(sies)
```

SALIDA:

> ```
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 25), match='34567'>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.057 s
> Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
> ```

Comment: Hola Mauricio, tendrías que explicar que **casos debería validar y que casos no tu expresión** porque no queda claro el objetivo final. Lógicamente el resultado es el esperado ya que `\d` expresa coincidencia con cualquier dígito, equivalente a `[0-9]`, por lo que en '34567' el 3 se corresponde con '[3-6]' , luego  4, 5, 6 y 7 cada uno con un `\d`  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[3-6]\d\d\d\d` significa:

```
[3-6]      # **Un solo número** que puede ser 3,4,5 o 6
\d\d\d\d   # Cuatro números cualesquiera
```

Así pues es normal que te encuentre 34567 ya que el 3 cumple con [3-6] y 4567 cumple con \d\d\d\d

Para hacer que **todos** los números solo puedan ir del 3 al 6 deberías haber hecho algo como esto:

`[3-6][3-6][3-6][3-6][3-6]`

o alternativamente `[3-6]{5}` (significa [3-6] repetido 5 veces)